# Finding and Excluding Columns of Dataframe with Certain Patterns in Header Names with R

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to find a solution to a data frame subsetting need I have.

I have a data frame that with the following general structure I have named `wrkDat`

```
A    R2_A    B    R2_B    .....    Z    R2_Z
1.1  0.99    2.2  0.97    .....    26.6 0.96
1.9  0.89    4.2  0.99    .....    12.8 0.78
```

I would like to be able to selectively subset so I don't have the R2 columns.
Initially I was thinking something like the following would work, but it does not.

```
selected <- "^R2." %in% colnames(wrkDat)
wrkDat <- wrkDat[,!selected]
```

Comment: have a look at [`grep`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html)

Comment: `selected <- grep('^R2.', names(wrkDat))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to Mitra and plafort for getting me thinking about the grep functions.  I found the following that worked perfectly. I don't know what I was thinking trying to use regex patterns with %in%....

```
selected <- grepl("^R2.", colnames(wrkDat))
wrkDat <- wrkDat[,!selected]
```

Comment: :) - You should indicate that it is resolved now (BTW, you forgot a missing parenthesis)

Comment: Thanks for catching the parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

```
wrkDat <- wrkDat[,-grep("^R2.",colnames(wrkDat)]
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(-starts_with("R2"))
```